# what is the difference between aws-apigatewayv2 and aws-apigatewayv2-alpha

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm trying to implement aws AGW. but I'm a little confused as the CDK documentation only referred to aws-apigatewayv2-alpha but there is an aws-apigatewayv2 without the word alpha at the trailing part of the library name.

I tried them both the only difference is when I'm trying to create an HttpApi construct, if I import this module from aws-apigatewayv2 it doesn't accept `this` as the correct argument of the stack scope.
But if I change this to aws-apigatewayv2-alpha that problem will be resolved.

Here is my sample code:

```
export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    const api = new apigatewayv2.HttpApi(this, 'MyHttpApi');
}
```

**To sum it up:**
which lib is the correct lib to use?
And if I can go with aws-apigatewayv2 which I assume is the stable version, how can I pass the stack scope to it without an issue?

Comment: Somehow it does. based on the accepted answer the aws-apigatewayv2 is located on CDK version 1 so I assume we can not use it on CDK V2.
I'll have to go with the alpha.